# Search by criteria not returning any records

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to check if the POST or the GET has my search variables and then add the variables to my query. I then want to pass the array name of those variables into the URL for paginating my search results. With someone's help, this is how far I have gone.

```
$criteria = array('ctitle', 'csubject', 'creference', 'cat_id', 'cmaterial', 'ctechnic', 'cartist', 'csource', 'stolen');
$likes = "";
$url_criteria = '';
foreach ( $criteria AS $criterion ) {
if ( ! empty($_POST[$criterion]) ) {
$value = ($_POST[$criterion]);
$likes .= " AND `$criterion` = '%$value%'";
$url_criteria .= '&amp;'.$criterion.'='.htmlentities($_POST[$criterion]);
} elseif ( ! empty($_GET[$criterion]) ) {
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[$criterion]);
$likes .= " AND `$criterion` = '%$value%'";
$url_criteria .= '&amp;'.$criterion.'='.htmlentities($_GET[$criterion]);
}
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM collections WHERE c_id>0" . $likes . " ORDER BY c_id ASC";
echo $sql;
```

The problem I have here is that after modifying the query I had before, any criteria I use to search does not return any records even when those records exist. I also echoed thequery and it printed the following line:

```
SELECT * FROM collections WHERE c_id>0 AND `cmaterial` = '%wood%' ORDER BY c_id ASC
```

Please, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use LIKE keyword instead of = when concatenating parts of criteria. Your condition means searching for exact match including % symbols, while LIKE means searching by pattern.

```
$likes .= " AND `$criterion` LIKE '%$value%'";
```

Comment: Thank you Zavg. That solved the query. But am also concerned with my pagination. I search by two criteria (category, cmaterial) but query only printed this line: SELECT * FROM collections WHERE c_id>0 AND `cat_id` LIKE '%2.\'%' ORDER BY c_id ASC Couldn't execute query and in the URL it was: ...gallery.php?s=8%27.&cat_id=2&cmaterial=wood.%27. Where could be the problem?

Comment: Try to debug the code checking if the criteria concatenation is performed two times. Add var_dump($likes) to elseif block after concatenation

Comment: This is what is printed: string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(24) " AND `cat_id` LIKE '%2%'" string(57) " AND `cat_id` LIKE '%2%' AND `cmaterial` LIKE '%wood.\'%'" string(57) " AND `cat_id` LIKE '%2%' AND `cmaterial` LIKE '%wood.\'%'" string(57) " AND `cat_id` LIKE '%2%' AND `cmaterial` LIKE '%wood.\'%'" string(57) " AND `cat_id` LIKE '%2%' AND `cmaterial` LIKE '%wood.\'%'" string(57) " AND `cat_id` LIKE '%2%' AND `cmaterial` LIKE '%wood.\'%'" Couldn't execute query. You are right the query may be repeating itself but how do I resolve this?

Comment: That seems to be ok, so $sql var should contain " AND cat_id LIKE '%2%' AND cmaterial LIKE '%wood.\'%"

Comment: This is how the link appears:  echo '<a href="myurl.php?page=1'.$url_criteria.'" title="Page 1">Page 1</a>';
But I am not getting it why the NEXT PREVIOUS links are not returning records.

Comment: Sorry zavg, the link is as follows: echo "&nbsp;<a href=\"$PHP_SELF?s=$news'.$url_criteria.'\">Next 10 &gt;&gt;</a>"; But am not sure it is correctly formated. Still not retruning matching records.

Comment: Thank you zavg for your assistance. I have the links now working after removing the '. .' Stay well.